# Open Local PDF in external Application from Android Studio HTML document

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

Currently making a WebView HTML app, and my links to local PDF files (paths are relative), are not working. I just want it to open in an external application (not within the WebView). I have tried multiple PDF intents from this site with no success.

I originally had the `Override` above the `public Boolean launchPDF` but kept getting

```
:method does not override or implement  method from a supertype
```

I need this to be a blanket statement for all PDFs as I have many of them.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    }

    public boolean launchPDF(WebView view, String url) {
        if (urlIsPDF(url)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
            try {
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                //User does not have pdf viewer installed
            }
        } else {
            myWebView.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean urlIsPDF(String url) {
        return url.endsWith(".pdf");
    }
};
```

Comment: "my links to local PDF files" -- what do you mean by this? Your HTML is coming from `assets/`. If your PDF files are also in `assets/`, you will not be able to view them the way that you are trying to.

Comment: I have a folder structure will heaps of PDF files in the assets folder (it replicates my web server). I need it to be offline as this will mainly be accessed out of service. How could I get them to work locally then?

Comment: only because I am using the same files to access these files within the folders on the server. Could I manually put them in a folder on the device and then some how redirect the link of any pdf (*.pdf) to the folder (eg Downloads or AppPdfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) to be able to serve PDF files from your app, directly from `assets/`. This is not too tough to set up and does not require you to copy any data at runtime. You would use a `StreamProvider`-supplied `Uri` in your `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`. However, this does not work with all PDF viewers, notably not the one that is part of the Google Drive app, until they fix their bugs.

If you want greater compatibility, copy the assets to files on the local filesystem (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), then use `FileProvider` from the Android Support Library. Other than having to do the copying, this has the same basic effect as does using `StreamProvider`. Serving from files, rather than directly from in-APK assets, improves compatibility with PDF viewers, though a few may still have hiccups due to bugs in how they handle `content` `Uri` values.

Yet another option is to embed some sort of PDF-viewing capability into your app. In [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html), I outline three options. They all have tradeoffs in terms of compatibility and size, and none are as full-featured as a standalone PDF viewer.

Or, you could find some tool to convert your PDFs to HTML/CSS/images, package that stuff in your app, and show that stuff in the `WebView`.

Comment: Ok, is there any chance you could give me a sample of how to insert the StreamProvider? It seems like it will be the best option for me. These files would be best kept somewhere in the App as I don't want the user the ability to delete them.

Comment: @MitchellDay: "I don't want the user the ability to delete them" -- well, the user cannot delete them from your app's portion of what the Android SDK refers to as [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Even if the user clears data, you would just turn around and copy them from assets again. With regards to `StreamProvider`, in addition to the demo project in the CWAC-Provider repo, I use it in some of my book examples, such as [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.5/DragDrop/SplitScreen/app/src/main/assets).

Comment: Ok, so how do I store the data their? do I leave it in the assets folder then it copies it over on installing? Also is there a way of making an Intent that does a blanket statement for opening PDFs? I've noticed that they all seem to defined for a pdf rather than pdf files in general. Again sorry, extremely new to this, I'm primarily web development.

Comment: @MitchellDay: "do I leave it in the assets folder then it copies it over on installing?" -- no, you would have to copy it over yourself. "Also is there a way of making an Intent that does a blanket statement for opening PDFs?" -- no, sorry. You can use `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to have the user choose a PDF, then view that PDF, though.